# .NET : How to use JIT compiler

Tags: .net, compilation, jit

I would like to use directly the .NET JIT Compiler, is it possible ?

I mean, I would like to do a thing like :

?> jit.exe myfile.msil myfile.exe

Or in a c# code ?

Comment: So what you want to do is generate an executable that is *not* interpreted anymore (i.e. native code)?

Comment: yes ! but with the same compiler used by the clr at execution

Comment: @Abel, that's 0 out of 4... not nearly as bad as the 0 out of 100+ people that are around here.

Comment: @Matthew: really, does it get that bad? But indeed, four q., that's a small list.

Comment: @Able I hope not... I normally don't even look until someone else points it out.  :o)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is *roughly* [ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx).

Note that although this generates native code:

- It still runs within the CLR (the managed runtime)
- The original IL is still maintained (so it can be recompiled if the processor has changed or something similar)
- The optimizations performed by ngen and the JIT can differ

IMO, ngen is usually not appropriate... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hmm not sure it's a good way because what I want to do is to test JIT compiler... (fuzzing, performance, etc...)

Comment: @Thomas: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? Do you need to examine the JIT-compiled code? What couldn't you do just by running the code and letting the JIT do its stuff at execution time?

Comment: @Thomas: If your code is malformed, won't that mess up the JIT as well? Starting with malformed code doesn't sound like a good plan. Again, it would really help if you would provide more context.

Comment: @Thomas: Given that we're trying to help you, you might want to provide more than single word responses. Edit your question to give the full background of what you're trying to do, why, why you need to JIT compile for it to work, and why you believe that JIT compilation would be successful but just running it wouldn't. The word "fuzzing" could have a number of different meanings here - the more detail you can give, the less likely it will be that we'll misunderstand you.